# Save an .xls file and then overwrite existing .xls file in Python 2.7

Tags: excel, python-2.7

What I am trying to do:

1. Download an XLS file from the internet (in my code example from below, I'm pulling from Google Sheets, but in the future I'm going to download directly via URL)
2. Save a new copy of that file, and add the date time to the file name. (so i have a folder with testexcel_05_24_2016.xlsx, testexcelt_05_25_2016.xlsx and so forth)
3. Over write an existing "master" file. i.e. save testexcel as masterexcel.xls

Here's my code:

```
import gspread
#export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="XXXXX"

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('XXXX', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("TestSheet").sheet1 #this is the sheet I'm opening
nst = open('NSTtest.xlsx', 'w') #trying to open 'master file'
nst.write(wks) #trying to overwrite master file with new file
nst.close()
os.rename(wks, "wks.xlsx") #trying to save new file. This is where I would add the date time
```

The error I get when I run this is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gspreadtest.py", line 14, in <module>
    nst.write(wks)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Aschs-MacBook-Air:learningpython aschharwood$

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're not telling us where the error occurs (always post the full traceback) but I suspect it's happening here: `os.rename(wks, "wks.xlsx")`. `wks` is not a file name but an open file, a file object. Change it to `os.rename("TestSheet", "wks.xlsx")` or whatever the old file name is *after* closing the file.

Comment: I just added the whole traceback.